# How can I get a list of all installed apps?

Tags: android

Greetings! I want to receive the list of the established appendices in the Android. But the list is displayed only in LogCat. How to write, that it was displayed on phone? 
I use the given code:
**java:**

```
package com.tipfile;     
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;

public class dop extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    ArrayList<ResolveInfo> list = (ArrayList<ResolveInfo>) 
    pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list) {
    System.out.println("Installed Applications "  + rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
    }}}
```

**xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textSelest"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**The translator wrote through online. I do not know English language.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getInstalledPackages()`:

```
List pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages();
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledPackages%28int%29

Comment: The code is displayed in LogCat without problems. Well and here on phone that it was displayed, how it to make?

Comment: Help! All the same the black screen. Show as it is necessary to add a code. Thanks.